# Hibernate Neo4j retrieve result in a key-value form

Tags: java, hibernate, neo4j, hibernate-ogm, hibernate-native-query

I would like to retrieve entity properties in a format like this: `property_name: value`.

I am trying to get the result this way:

```
public void retrievePerson(){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
      try{

         String query = "MATCH (p:Person {id:3}) RETURN p.firstname, p.lastname";

         List<Object[]> person = (List<Object[]>) em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();

         em.flush();
         tx.commit();
         em.clear();
         em.close();
         emf.close();

      }
      catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }
   }
```

I read somewhere the the object returned by the query is a managed entity.

I would like the result to be like this: `{"firstname":"Jon", "lastname":"Smith"}`

I have found this `setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE` which might be something that I am looking for but I am unable to get it to work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query to:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id:3})
RETURN { firstname: p.firstname, lastname: p.lastname }
```

Comment: This works fine. I am getting a result like this `[{firstname=Jon, lastname=Smith}]` . I can convert this array into a proper JSON afterwards.

Comment: @Porjaz Try this trick: `MATCH (p:Person {id:3})
RETURN collect({ firstname: p.firstname, lastname: p.lastname })[0]`

Comment: It still gives them in the same format `[{firstname=Jon, lastname=Smith}]`

Comment: @Porjaz This is probably related to the way your Java code is converting the query result. I suggest you to ask a new question about it.

Comment: Its not that big of a problem. I can write a code to convert it to a proper json. Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the returned value to be an entity, this will work:

```
String query = "MATCH (p:Person {id:3}) RETURN p";
List<Person> person = (List<Person>) em.createNativeQuery(query, Person.class).getResultList();
```

Actually, in this case this would make more sense:

```
    Person poem = (Person) em.createNativeQuer(query, Person.class).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I think this is not quite what I am looking for. I am trying to return a subgraph (a family tree) so the query is quite big. That's why I need to return every person's firstname, lastname, relationship, relationship_property, etc. Bruno Peres's  query returns the data in a close way that I was looking for. It returned `[{firstname=Jon, lastname=Smith}]`. Ideally it would be best if the returned result could be in a json format

Comment: Hibernate OGM currently does not support ResultTransformers, I've created an issue for it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-1328